# Why can't I connect to TYPO3 extension repository (trying to devellop on server2go)?

Tags: curl, repository, typo3

When I try to install a language package in TYPO3 4.7 on server2go, I get this error

```
router
tx_em_Repository_Utility: Could not access remote resource 
http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz
```

I already did a Google search on that and found the suggestion to enable cURL in the php.ini: `extension=php_curl.dll` (by searching the filesystem I ensured this DLL does exist).

What am I missing? Could there be any other reasons I can't connect to repository?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is maybe do iptable restrictions from hoster. Try to use curl or contact your hoster an tell them to add a iptable rule alá `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d repositories.typo3.org -j ACCEPT`.

hi try to define testserver.. a local machine,vm..? basicaly this is a firewall rule for linux to allow get data from outside on port 80 .. time ago i had this problem.

have u tried to get files with curl (TYPO3 installtool) ?

```
[SYS][curlUse] = 1
```

Comment: Ah, this sounds interesting! As mentioned, I'm currently running this just on a testserver. Could I do it for this as well? Where would I have to enter this command? Thanks a lot so far!